How to open an epub at exact location with OEBPS Section point
Kobo annotations files store the location of the annotated text the followoing way:
<fragment start="OEBPS/Section0002.xhtml#point(/1/4/2/180/1:556)" end=...

I would like to open an epub with an ebook viewer (or whatever) and jump exactly to this position (running on GNU/Linux).
